# What's the most efficient way to have a method that takes an indexable list of any type in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, performance, boxing

I want to be able to edit any or most of the generic list types that use an indexer in C#, like so:

```
void testIList(System.Collections.IList someList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++)
    {
        someList[i] = someList.Count - i;
    }
}

void test()
{
    int[] intArray = new int[10];
    List<int> intList = new List<int>();
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        intList.Add(0);
        stringList.Add("test");
    }

    testIList(intArray);
    testIList(intList);

    testIList(stringList);
}
```

The code works, but of course there's no compile-time error for testIList(stringList), which is undesirable.

Also, is there boxing and unboxing occuring in testIList that I can avoid by using some more specific generic collection as the type in the parameter?

Comment: Why not use generics? [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the generic interface for `IList`: `IList<T>`:

```
void testIList<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IList<T> someList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++)
    {
        someList[i] = default(T);
    }
}
```

Of course, you have to find out yourself what is the logic to determine the value to set the list items to, but at least `default(T)` will show you the code works.

Comment: I think you could even use `IEnumerable<T>` since it's less specific than `IList<T>` and could support even more "generic list types"

Comment: That doesn't support indexed assignments @BoredomOverload

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>` interface to only allow for those collections that implement that, which would be `List<int>`, `int[]` and some others. It would not allow a non-generic list type like `ArrayList` or a `List<object>` (with which your current code would work) but that's more often a good thing to block rather than a bad thing.

```
void TestIList(IList<int> someList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.Count; i++)
    {
        someList[i] = someList.Count - i;
    }
}
```